# Django date format in template : %B causes "No exception message supplied" error

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I'm trying to format a datetime in a template with Django, and I have a strange problem.

I have a simple loop :

```
<tbody>
       {% for event in events %}
       <tr>                                     
          <td>
              <strong>Le {{event.start}}</strong>                                          
          </td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

It works great, the date looks like that : "Le 9 janvier 2015 10:00:00"

If I use `{{event.start|date:"d b Y"}}` it still works. I have a date like :"Le 09 jan 2015"

BUT, if I use `{{event.start|date:"d B Y"}}`, in order to have the Month as locale’s full name ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)) I get this error :

```
NotImplementedError at /annuler-rendez-vous/
No exception message supplied
```

And I have absolutely no idea why I get this problem only when I use "B".

Any help would be very much appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: Ok, I just found that django templatetag filtering of datetime is different from python strftime(). See : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date Anyway, I still wonder why this problem happened !

Comment: It says right there in the link you just provided: `B` is not implemented, therefore the exception.

Answer (score 2):

The "B" format is not implemented. You can use the format "F" which does exactly the same.
I found it looking at the code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/dateformat.py#L225

Your code will look like this:

```
{{event.start|date:"d F Y"}}
```